# JQuery Datatable Error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am getting data for my DataTable from another URL on my website called **request.php**.

**request.php:**

```
$con = mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
$con or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_logins") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

$resultArray = array();
$tempArray = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // Add each row into our results array
    $tempArray = $row;
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}

echo json_encode($resultArray);

mysql_close($con);
```

Here is my HTML & JQuery for the DataTable.

**table.html:**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>
<body>
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>uEmail</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


    </table>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sAjaxSource": "http://xxxx.net/request",
                "sAjaxDataProp": "data"
        } );
    } );
  </script>
</body>
```

When **request.php** is manually accessed, this is what is displayed:
`[{"uEmail":"xxxx@gmail.com","time":"06-07-2015 7:55 pm","location":"xx.xx.xx.xxx"},{"uEmail":"xxxx@gmail.com","time":"06-07-2015 5:45 pm","location":"xx.xx.xx.xxx"}]`

In the console, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Here is a screenshot of the DataTable and console. [image: Screenshot of DataTable and console error]

Comment: Dumb question on my part but I gotta ask, I know you have masked your URLs in your code sample, but you have `http://xxxx.net/request` being passed to dataTables, but then you say `request.php` so does the param you pass to dataTable need to be `http://xxxx.net/request.php`?

Comment: Is the JSON returned when you look in the network inspector? Also, is it /request.php or /request?

Comment: My .htaccess takes care of extension-less URLs, however I tried it with http://xxxx.net/request.php and I still get the same error.

Comment: The type is 'document' under Network. I can provide a screenshot if you'd like. I read somewhere that `"sAjaxDataProp": "data"` takes care of the fact that content returned is not JSON. @Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the DataTables 1.9 documentation, sAjaxDataProp specifies the name of the array inside the returned JSON object that contains the entries.
At the same time, DataTables appears to accept entries as arrays, not objects.

Your return format should be:

`{"data": [["xxxx@gmail.com","06-07-2015 7:55 pm","xx.xx.xx.xxx"],["xxxx@gmail.com","06-07-2015 5:45 pm","xx.xx.xx.xxx"]]}`

Comment: I removed `sAjaxDataProp` and now I am getting "Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries" at the bottom of the table. However my entries are not being displayed in the table itself.

Comment: By default, the array that DataTables looks for is "aaData"; try using the format specified above, but with `"aaData"` instead of `"data"`.

Comment: Here is the alert that appears: "DataTables warning (table id = 'example'): Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0"

Comment: I tried what you said and I am getting "Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries" at the bottom of the table. But entries not being displayed. I also get the same alert message.

Comment: It appears that the entries are processed as arrays and not objects. Could you try using `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc`?